# web3.js Error: the method personal_listAccounts does not exist/is not available

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

- **Code:**

  ```
  var Web3 = require('web3');
  var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));


  var sender = web3.eth.accounts[0];
  console.log('Sender: ' + sender);

  web3.personal.listAccounts;
  ```
- **Output:**

  ```
  Sender: 0xA0A0A01


  home/ubuntuuser/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:61
      throw errors.InvalidResponse(result);
      ^
  Error: The method personal_listAccounts does not exist/is not available
  at Object.module.exports.InvalidResponse (/home/ubuntuuser/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:16)
  at RequestManager.send (/home/ubuntuuser/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:61:22)
  at Personal.get [as listAccounts] (/home/ubuntuuser/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/property.js:107:62)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntuuser/Desktop/Ethereum/ethy.js:63:14)
  at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
  at startup (node.js:136:18)
  ```

---

- **Question:**

From the above, commands like `web3.eth.accounts[0]` works fine, however `web3.personal.listAccounts;` doesn't. Why might that be the case?

Comment: How did you launch geth? It can be that you have missed enabling the personal api from the command line, try adding `personal` to the `--rpcapi` something like this `geth --rpc --rpcapi eth,web3,net,ssh,db,debug,personal` enable serveral apis.

Comment: @Ismael this worked! :) :) thank you so much. If you make an answer explaining that I will give it the checkmark

Comment: Note that this can be very unsafe; there is a reason why the `personal` interface isn't exposed over RPC by default. You can do this more safely over IPC https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-can-i-make-new-account-by-json-rpc

Comment: oh thanks @TjadenHess this is really important. I'll try out the method in that post there. Would leaving the --rpc in `geth --rpc` also cause a security risk? or was it just the `--rpcapi ...`?