# transfer all ether from one account to a smart contract with ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, gas-price, gas-estimate

i want to transfer ALL the ether in my account to the smart contract.
I am calculating the gasEstimate and then subtracting it from my total ether balance...but i get an ERROR saying **code: -32000, message: 'gas required exceeds allowance (13179)'**

````
const grantorEtherBalance: number = Number(
      ethers.utils.formatUnits(await provider.getBalance(grantorAddress), 'ether'),
    )
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider)
const psigner = wallet.connect(provider)

    //send the ether from grantor's wallet to smart contract
    const forGasEstimatetx = {
      to: '0xa013618172F9E3514843CBF3a45221479A2E4297',
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther('0'),
    }
const gasEstimate: any = await wallet.estimateGas(forGasEstimatetx)

    const sub = feeData * parseInt(gasEstimate)

    const sendingEther = grantorEtherBalance - sub

    const tx = {
      to: '0xa013618172F9E3514843CBF3a45221479A2E4297',
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther(sendingEther.toString()),
    }
    const transaction = await psigner.sendTransaction(tx)


    const receipt = await transaction.wait()
    console.log('receipt', receipt)```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I send the entire ether balance from one account to another account?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19282/how-do-i-send-the-entire-ether-balance-from-one-account-to-another-account)

Comment: you better transfer all the funds to another account (EOA) you are using, and then from there, transfer to the contract. Because when you call the contract with the balance of the calling account emptied many irregularities can happen. EstimateGas() function is not 100% precise, and in your case, it has failed to calculate the gas  to clear the balance completely. Thats why it is better to empty and account into another EOA instead of a contract

Comment: Try setting the value to a non zero ether amount to calculate the estimation. Also, set the gas limit, and gas price in the final transaction. In some cases, in complex contracts, the gas limit might need to be greater due to the estimation being dependant on the contract state. It could happend to leave some ether behind due to gas refund.