# How to transfer entire address balance to another address

Tags: web3js, gas, javascript, gas-price, gas-limit

After going through the questions [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/5759/133019) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/19282/133019) I came up with the code below to transfer the entire balance from one address to another using web3.js.

```
export async function sendTransaction(
  secretKey: string,
  amount: number,
  to?: string
) {
  try {
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(secretKey, provider);
    const valueAfterGas = amount - gasLimit;
    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();

    const tx = await wallet.sendTransaction({
      to: to,
      value: valueAfterGas,
      gasLimit: gasLimit * Number(gasPrice),
    });

    return tx;
  } catch (error) {
    log(`No transaction for ${amount} to ${to}`);
    errorHandler(error);
  }
}
```

This code doesn't work and I get RPC errors saying -

`Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit`

`Error: processing response error`

How can this be fixed? I am using web3 version 4.4, if your solution requires a different version I can downgrade if it can be specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miscalculate the `valueAfterGas` and the `gasLimit`.

- `gasLimit` has nothing to do with the price. It defines how much gas will be consumed in the transaction. For ETH transfer this value is: `21000`
- `valueAfterGas = amount - gasLimit * gasPrice;` (*gasPrice is per 1 GAS unit*)
- you should pass your `gasPrice` to the transaction.

```typescript
const tx = await wallet.sendTransaction({
   to: to,
   value: amount - gasLimit * gasPrice,
   gasPrice: gasPrice,
   gasLimit: gasLimit,
});
```